# SDL Key blocking and ghosting

Tags: c++, sdl

I have been using `SDL` to make a 2d game in `c++` and have found that some key combinations don't work.

For example, if I hold the left and up arrow keys, `SDL` doesn't recognize the right arrow key being pressed.  After some research, I found this is probably due to key blocking or ghosting, and that there is no solution.

How do other programmers get around this?

I haven't encountered this limitation while playing most existing games. I have never encountered this problem in Java.

Here is a sample of code:

```
while(SDL_PollEvent(&event))
{

    if(event.type == SDL_KEYDOWN)
    {
        switch(event.key.keysym.sym)
        {
            case SDLK_UP:
                std::cout << "Up pressed" << std::endl;
            break;
            case SDLK_DOWN:
                std::cout << "Down pressed" << std::endl;
            break;
            case SDLK_LEFT:
                std::cout << "Left pressed" << std::endl;
            break;
            case SDLK_RIGHT:
                std::cout << "Right pressed" << std::endl;
            break;
        }
    }
    else if(event.type == SDL_KEYUP)
    {
        switch(event.key.keysym.sym)
        {
            case SDLK_UP:
                std::cout << "Up released" << std::endl;
            break;
            case SDLK_DOWN:
                std::cout << "Down released" << std::endl;
            break;
            case SDLK_LEFT:
                std::cout << "Left released" << std::endl;
            break;
            case SDLK_RIGHT:
                std::cout << "Right released" << std::endl;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: do you mean that this issue does not come up with the same setup when using java instead of c++ and sdl?

Comment: how about showing the offending code?

Comment: @didierc That is exactly what i mean

Comment: If it works in other contexts, then it's not blocking or ghosting, since those terms describe hardware limitations of some keyboards (usually the cheap ones.) Java would not be able to get the key presses if that was the case. Please provide a minimal code sample that we can run and that demonstrates the problem you're having.

Comment: I don''t know why your question has been upvoted, I had to ask you for clarifications, which proved you did not provide the means for us to verify your claims.

Comment: @NikosC. I have provided a sample of code

Answer (score 1):

There isn't really a way around this because it's keyboard specific. For example, on my laptop keyboard, I can only press a certain number of keys at once if certain keys are pressed.

You could try reducing the number of keys that someone has to press at once, but it will be tricky.